# GRASS raster calculator - fill nodata values from other raster

Tags: raster, grass-gis, raster-calculator, merge, grass-7.0

I want to use `r.mapcalc` to calculate a raster from two inputs: `water_rst` and `contour_rst`. I need a raster with all values from `water_rst` and then values from `contour_rst` where `water_rst` has `no data`.

An expression like `comb_rst = not(if(water_rst))*contour_rst` produces raster with only contour values, but no initial water values. How to modify this expression to get both water values and contours?

Answer (score 1):

This expression does the trick: `if(isnull(water_rst), contour_rst, water_rst)`